# Problem with align* in math mode

Tags: math-mode, errors, amsmath

I'd like to ask why the command `align` doesn't work. My text goes like this:

```
\begin{align*}
$f(g_{1}{g_{2}}^{-1} ) & = f(g_{1}) \cdot f({g_{2}}^{-1})$ dato che $f$ omomorfismo \\

&= $f(g_{1}) \cdot f(g_{2})^{-1}$ dato che $f$ è omomorfismo \\

&= $f(g_{1}) \cdot f(g_{1})^{-1}$ , segue da $f(g_{1}) = f(g_{2})$ \\

&= $e'$
\end{align*}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't compile, my code is wrong, I'd like to know where.

Are there some packages to be added which I'm ignoring?

Comment: It's the same answer: please, read a basic guide.

Comment: this is unrelated to texshop, that is just the editor you used to write the file. You need to delete all the `$` and all the blank lines, and please always post complete examples and show the error message that you get.

Comment: “Computes” means “compiles”, I guess…

Comment: Did you load `amsmath` or `mathtools`?

Comment: Yes, my mistake @GuM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read a basic guide. Within `align*` you are already in math mode, so `$` is forbidden (it isn't in the scope of `\text`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Some text to fill a couple of lines before some displayed
equation that is centered on a line by itself
\begin{equation*}
f(g_{1})=f(g_{2})
\end{equation*}
and some text following the display. Now we have a more
complex one.
\begin{align*}
f(g_{1}{g_{2}}^{-1} ) & = f(g_{1}) \cdot f({g_{2}}^{-1})
 &&\text{dato che $f$ è omomorfismo} \\
&= f(g_{1}) \cdot f(g_{2})^{-1}
 &&\text{dato che $f$ è omomorfismo} \\
&= f(g_{1}) \cdot f(g_{1})^{-1},
 &&\text{segue da $f(g_{1}) = f(g_{2})$} \\
&= e'
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]